# MySQL to SQL Server - Unixtime being major problem

Tags: sql-server, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to convert this query to SQL Server.

It already has a lot of updates. Still, I don't know what to do from here ( i'm not the best when it comes to programming in MySQL )

```
 SELECT wo.WORKORDERID,
dpt.DEPTNAME "Department",
aau.USER_ID,
aau.FIRST_NAME "Requester", 
sadt.RATING "Rating Value", 
spre.COMMENTS "Comments",
    FROM_UNIXTIME((spre.CREATEDTIME/1000)) "criacao da pesquisa",
    #FROM_UNIXTIME((wo.RESPONDEDTIME/1000)) "Resposta da pesquisa",
            MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME((spre.CREATEDTIME)/1000)) "Mes Pesquisa",
            YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME((spre.CREATEDTIME)/1000)) "Ano Pesquisa",
#wo.RESPONDEDTIME "RespondedTime", 
aau1.FIRST_NAME "Technician"
    FROM SurveyPerRequest spr 
INNER JOIN SurveyPerRequestExt spre ON spr.SURVEYID=spre.SURVEYID 
LEFT JOIN SurveyDetails sdt ON spre.SURVEYID=sdt.SURVEYID 
LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers sadt ON sdt.SURANSID=sadt.SURANSID 
LEFT JOIN WorkOrder wo ON spr.WORKORDERID=wo.WORKORDERID
LEFT JOIN SDUser sdu ON wo.REQUESTERID=sdu.USERID 
LEFT JOIN AaaUser aau ON sdu.USERID=aau.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN WorkOrderStates wos ON wo.WORKORDERID=wos.WORKORDERID
LEFT JOIN SDUser sdu1 ON wos.OWNERID=sdu1.USERID 
LEFT JOIN AaaUser aau1 ON sdu1.USERID=aau1.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN DepartmentDefinition dpt ON wo.DEPTID=dpt.DEPTID
    WHERE (spre.CREATEDTIME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 00:00:00')*1000) AND (spre.CREATEDTIME <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-31 23:59:59')*1000)
AND aau.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%Pumputis%'
        ORDER BY spre.CREATEDTIME
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned `Unixtime being major problem`

Please note how [**FROM_UNIXTIME()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) is being used

```
FROM_UNIXTIME((spre.CREATEDTIME/1000)) "criacao da pesquisa",
```

From this line, here is what I can tell:

- `spre.CREATEDTIME` is number of milliseconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`
- [**FROM_UNIXTIME()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) requires the number of seconds, not milliseconds
- `spre.CREATEDTIME` has to be divided by 1000 before calling [**FROM_UNIXTIME()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Based on someone else's post in StackOverflow ([Truncate Datetime to Second (Remove Milliseconds) in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9019047/491757)), you will have to change it to something like:

```
CONVERT(datetime,char(19),spre.CREATEDTIME/1000,126) "criacao da pesquisa",
```

Please read [***T-SQL Documentation on CONVERT***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

> what is this # in front of some sentences??

[The `#` character as the first character makes that whole line a comment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comments.html)

When you execute this script, only the first `SELECT` is executed

The other `SELECT` queries and the one `UPDATE` query are not executed

The first query has comments as well. If you ignore those two lines, this is what really runs:

```
 SELECT wo.WORKORDERID,
dpt.DEPTNAME "Department",
aau.USER_ID,
aau.FIRST_NAME "Requester", 
sadt.RATING "Rating Value", 
spre.COMMENTS "Comments",
    FROM_UNIXTIME((spre.CREATEDTIME/1000)) "criacao da pesquisa",
            MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME((spre.CREATEDTIME)/1000)) "Mes Pesquisa",
            YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME((spre.CREATEDTIME)/1000)) "Ano Pesquisa",
aau1.FIRST_NAME "Technician"
    FROM SurveyPerRequest spr 
INNER JOIN SurveyPerRequestExt spre ON spr.SURVEYID=spre.SURVEYID 
LEFT JOIN SurveyDetails sdt ON spre.SURVEYID=sdt.SURVEYID 
LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers sadt ON sdt.SURANSID=sadt.SURANSID 
LEFT JOIN WorkOrder wo ON spr.WORKORDERID=wo.WORKORDERID
LEFT JOIN SDUser sdu ON wo.REQUESTERID=sdu.USERID 
LEFT JOIN AaaUser aau ON sdu.USERID=aau.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN WorkOrderStates wos ON wo.WORKORDERID=wos.WORKORDERID
LEFT JOIN SDUser sdu1 ON wos.OWNERID=sdu1.USERID 
LEFT JOIN AaaUser aau1 ON sdu1.USERID=aau1.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN DepartmentDefinition dpt ON wo.DEPTID=dpt.DEPTID
    WHERE (spre.CREATEDTIME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 00:00:00')*1000) AND (spre.CREATEDTIME <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-31 23:59:59')*1000)
AND aau.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%Pumputis%'
        ORDER BY spre.CREATEDTIME
```

Answer (score 3):

so FROM_UNIXTIME is not a method within SQL SERVER that I have found however if what you are trying to do is write the above query in T-SQL I think this should work.

```
SELECT wo.WORKORDERID,
dpt.DEPTNAME "Department",
aau.USER_ID,
aau.FIRST_NAME "Requester", 
sadt.RATING "Rating Value", 
spre.COMMENTS "Comments",
DATEADD(SECOND,(spre.CREATEDTIME/1000),'1970-01-01') "criacao da pesquisa",
          DATEPART(MONTH,(DATEADD(SECOND,(spre.CREATEDTIME/1000),'1970-01-01'))) "Mes Pesquisa",
        DATEPART(YEAR,(DATEADD(SECOND,(spre.CREATEDTIME/1000),'1970-01-01'))) "Ano Pesquisa",
aau1.FIRST_NAME "Technician"
FROM SurveyPerRequest spr 
INNER JOIN SurveyPerRequestExt spre ON spr.SURVEYID=spre.SURVEYID 
LEFT JOIN SurveyDetails sdt ON spre.SURVEYID=sdt.SURVEYID 
LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers sadt ON sdt.SURANSID=sadt.SURANSID 
LEFT JOIN WorkOrder wo ON spr.WORKORDERID=wo.WORKORDERID
LEFT JOIN SDUser sdu ON wo.REQUESTERID=sdu.USERID 
LEFT JOIN AaaUser aau ON sdu.USERID=aau.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN WorkOrderStates wos ON wo.WORKORDERID=wos.WORKORDERID
LEFT JOIN SDUser sdu1 ON wos.OWNERID=sdu1.USERID 
LEFT JOIN AaaUser aau1 ON sdu1.USERID=aau1.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN DepartmentDefinition dpt ON wo.DEPTID=dpt.DEPTID
WHERE (spre.CREATEDTIME >= DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01','2014-04-01 00:00:00')*1000)
AND (spre.CREATEDTIME <= DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01','2014-08-31 23:59:59')*1000)
AND aau.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%Pumputis%'
ORDER BY spre.CREATEDTIME
```

Essentially to convert an existing tick to a unix timestamp you would want to

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,(utcTickValue),'1970-01-01')
```

And if you had a date you are trying to convert to ticks

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01',DateToConvert)
```